# Webpack Dependency Not Found

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I am new to Webpack and am trying to set it up as a bundler for a relatively simple project (some JS and SASS).

The problems are that one of the dependencies is not being found and that the Bootstrap is not being applied.

The error(s) in the console is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Plyr is not defined
>  http://localhost:8000/static/index.js:58
> n http://localhost:8000/static/index.js:1
>  http://localhost:8000/static/index.js:25
> n http://localhost:8000/static/index.js:1
>  http://localhost:8000/static/index.js:1
>  http://localhost:8000/static/index.js:1

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = {
    entry: { index: path.resolve(__dirname, "static_src", "index.js") },
    output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "static_compiled"),
    publicPath: "/static/", // Should match Django STATIC_URL
    filename: "[name].js",  // No filename hashing, Django takes care of this
    chunkFilename: "[id]-[chunkhash].js", // DO have Webpack hash chunk filename, see below
    },
    plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
    ],
    module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}, // to transform JSX into JS
        { test: /\.scss$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]},
        {test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]}
    ],
    },
    resolve: {
    alias: {
            shared: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'bower_components')
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', 'jsx', 'tsx']
    },
    devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true, // Write files to disk in dev mode, so Django can serve the assets
    }
}
```

**static_src/index.js**

```
import "./sass/main.scss";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
//import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
import 'bootstrap';
import 'jquery';
import 'plyr/dist/plyr.polyfilled.js';

import "./js/custom.js";
import "./js/clean-blog.js";
```

**from package.json**

```
   "dependencies": {
      "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
      "jquery": "^3.5.1",
      "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
      "plyr": "^3.5.10",
      "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
      "sass-lint": "^1.13.1"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
      "babel": "^6.23.0",
      "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
      "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
      "little-loader": "^0.2.0",
      "react": "^16.13.1",
      "sass": "^1.26.11",
      "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
      "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
      "webpack": "^4.44.1",
      "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
      "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
   }
```

**static_src/custom.js**

```
const player = new Plyr('#player', {});

// Expose player so it can be used from the console
window.player = player;
```

**from base.html template**

```
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<!-- <link href="{% static 'css/clean-blog.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"> -->
<!-- <link href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"> -->
<script src="{% static 'index.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On a separate note, I am not sure whether I am including the bundle into HTML properly. Should I have a separate CSS and JS inclusion?

Comment: It looks like there is somewhere in your code call `new Plyr()`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is located in `custom.js`. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Can you also share the code how did you do that?

Comment: Why don't you import to use the class `Plyr ` directly like: `import Plyr from 'plyr'` and also remove this import `import 'plyr/dist/plyr.polyfilled.js'` which is unnecessary I guess

Comment: @tmhao2005 That does not fix it. :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221814/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-madphysicist).